What does this community stand for?
I asked a question about the interpretation of self-conscious and received several serious answers. JSW's last answer was equally serious and also a request to use a dictionary instead of asking a question in this forum. My post was deleted.
I consulted several dictionaries beforehand.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org

https://www.merriam-webster.com/

https://www.wordreference.com/


JSW is right when he says that a single dictionary can easily give an answer. After comparing several dictionaries, there are often more questions than answers. I have asked these questions here. JSW is wrong in his request. This is easy to see if he had followed his own advice. And if I am not allowed to ask a well-prepared question here, then I am in the wrong place. What does this community stand for?

This isn't a question about the English language and you should be asking this on Meta SE. As far as I know ELU gives due regard to questions that are well thought out . Maybe, the question you asked didn't really belong here.

Without being able to see the deleted question it's hard to know what the problem was. It's not enough to say afterwards that you've consulted different dictionaries: you need to say in the question what the dictionaries say, you need to think about the differences between the entries and explain what you found, and say what else you need to know that isn't in the dictionaries.

I seem to remember that in the deleted question, commenters pointed out that it has different meanings in different contexts.

There seem to be two questions here: 1) about why the described question was deleted, and 2) what does this site in general stand for, ie what are its general principles (which might help explain why the particular question was closed/deleted)? The second can be fond by perusing the main site's questions and FAQ and the meta site, and following the site for a while. The first question should be asked directly.

@Wolfgang please give a link to the deleted question so that those who can view it and haven't seen it already attempt an explanation.

Saying 'Cambridge Dictionary lists, in order, the definition/s A, B, C ...' and 'Dictionary.another](htt....) gives B, A and Z' ... and C and Z seem to contradict each other' (ie actually showing [quoting] serious research, with links and attributions), would, I'd say, present a very valid question, // Note that, OED and M-W apart, dictionaries list different senses of a word in order of idiomaticity (so the most common usage first).

You speak about a “well- prepared question”! Can you please show us what the question was?

This "well-prepared question" lacked the full links to actual dictionary entries (only the dictionary front page) and also linked to some pages in German. I edited it before it was migrated here.

@WeatherVane I think the question they were talking about is the one now linked at the start of the question, not this one that's now on meta.

@Laurel thanks. This question was migrated from EL&U, wherein they were asking about a well-prepared question, but ironically failed to prepare this particular question.

I'm not sure who can see the timeline for what happened to this particular question, but that reveals why it was deleted.
The question was closed by receiving a number of votes citing the "Answered by a dictionary" reason. It received a reopen vote, but a review resulted in three "leave closed" votes.
Because it was closed and had received no answers and no upvotes, the system deleted it after it had been closed for nine days. This clear-up process is known as the Roomba (after the automatic room cleaner) and there's even a help page reachable with that name: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/roomba
As to what the community stands for, it manages "a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts."
For the record, there is a good question How much research is needed? with an answer which has gained quite a number of upvotes too.

The problem with the original question was not that it failed to display some elaborate research, but that, so far as could have been seen from the question, the OP seemed altogether unaware that the word has two distinct senses, which can be seen in just about any dictionary. Now, it is possible that the OP was, in fact, aware of it, and had something more sophisticated in mind, but that was not visible in the question as formulated. The question could have, arguably, been transformed into something interesting, but it was the responsibility of the OP to so transform it.

The basic problem is this: for many such questions, we can't do better than a dictionary.
People on this site may certainly be able to tell you their personal impressions of a word's connotations, but unless those impressions are shared with others they don't constitute part of its meaning and aren't particularly useful. The only way to objectively answer questions about a word's meaning is to consult third-party sources that try to describe the meaning of a word as commonly understood among most typical native speakers, based (ideally) on some level of research and written (ideally) by someone with expertise in the matter. Purely personal and subjective opinions about word meanings/connotations (or anything else) are not appropriate for this site unless backed up by reliable external sources that can confirm their broader validity.
There are cases where corpus research or even academic articles can settle the question of word meanings; since the reliable source wouldn't be a dictionary, that close reason wouldn't apply. I doubt that the OP's question is an example, but there are exception where non-dictionary-based research can be necessary and genuinely helpful, and those are on topic for this site, particularly if the question makes it clear why dictionary entries don't (or can't) settle the issue. I would nominate this question, and its excellent answer by yours truly, as an example.
I would add one exception. Non-native speakers may encounter an unusual level of difficulty in applying or understanding those dictionary definitions. But questions likely resulting from that belong on ELL, not on this site.

English language users often migrate to a dictionary to help determine the lexical definition of a term. For most users, the dictionary provides enough information to use an expression within an English sentence, so it seems fair to close a question about what can be found in a dictionary, since multiple dictionaries are likely to list the same parts of speech, point to related words and contexts, and cite a number of examples. Thus, small general differences in definitions in general dictionaries are usually ignored.
When the meaning of a word starts appearing contested, then generally we are past lexical definitions and are into conceptual questions. Unlike a general dictionary, a philosophical dictionary will start appearing a little more encyclopedic in scope, and if a term is really controversial, it might even be an essentially contested concept. As you move towards this latter case, you are no longer dealing with lexical definitions but are dealing with real definitions (setting aside a political fracas, for instance, that might lie at the heart of definist fallacy).
Thus, if you are dealing with an abstraction like consciousness, awareness, or intentionality, you are more in the realm of philosophical dispute and would be better off posting on Philosophy Stack Exchange. For instance, consciousness has an entry in the SEP which is over 30 PDF pages long (US letter). So, to try to craft a lexical definition from what is at its core essentially disputed (often for thousands of years) can be difficult for lexicographers. Plus, your average ELU enthusiast may not have an interest in the subtleties of language more broadly and lexicography.
If you have been trying to wrap your mind around this closure, and you find it interesting, you'd probably benefit from Harris and Hutton's Definition in Theory and Practice (GB). Expertise in a language is not expertise of language more generally, and questions of the latter can only be resolved (or rather explored, dissolution and solution being hard to come by in the canon) by philosophy of language.

It is true that questions occasionally appear on this site that are problematic because they call for elaborate philosophical analysis, that goes beyond the matters of 'English language and usage', as they are understood here. It is, however, far from clear that that was the problem with the question that the OP posted.

@jsw29 I think the other route to shunt off-topic, but related posts is ELL, then. As the site has been purged of the post in question, one can only leave a firm reminder ELU occupies a middle ground.
